# Git workflows with external developers

Tags: git, github, version-control, developer-tools

I’m trying to work out the best Git workflow to implement when working with external developers. Ideally, I would like to set up the initial commit and let the developers take it from there, but I would also like to ‘approve’/merge their commits. When I try to add contributors to my private repos on GitHub, it gives them permission to push to the repo, therefor I don’t have the ability to review prior to them merging the code.

Does anyone here have experience with version control workflows and external developers? What works, what doesn’t and what to look out for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fork A Repo" might help in this case. Don't add your external developers as contributors, ask them to fork your repository. With that way, they can submit a pull request to the project owner (you) when they have any commit. And you can review and decide to pull that change or not.
See [Fork A Repo on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks! That’s what I figured. I was not sure initially because I assumed it means that my external developers will have to use a paid GitHub account but apparently, even if they’re on free plans, the repo will remain private.